# applescript access switch control through system preferences

Tags: macos, applescript

My end goal is to click the "Enable Switch Control" checkbox, which can be found under Accessibility-> Switch Control in System Preferences. I have had some trouble getting the applescript to work and would like to find out what is causing the issue.
My current code:

```
if running of application "System Preferences" then
    quit application "System Preferences"
    delay 1
end if
    
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "Switch" of pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
    activate
end tell
```

I got the anchor Switch by using:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    get anchors of pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
end tell
```

which returned all of the available anchors. Here is a snippet:

> ...anchor **TextToSpeech** of pane id com.apple.preference.universalaccess, anchor **Dwell** of pane id com.apple.preference.universalaccess, anchor **Dictation** of pane id com.apple.preference.universalaccess, anchor **Switch** of pane id com.apple.preference.universalaccess, anchor **Siri** of pane id com.apple.preference.universalaccess...

I tried testing the applescript with other anchors (Dictation, Siri, etc) and they all worked (directed me to the intended area), but Switch doesn't. I even tried replacing "Switch" with its numerical value, `reveal anchor 11 of pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"`, but that also fails. Why is that? Also, how would I modify the applescript to get the intended result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a *bug* in that **System Preferences** will not properly `reveal anchor "Switch" of pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"` and as such, here is a workaround.

Note that the coding in the *example* **AppleScript** *code* assumes that **Switch Control** has once previously been turned on manually so as to answer the initial **System Preferences is trying to unlock Accessibility preferences** *dialog box* where you have entered your **User Name** and **Password** then clicked the **Unlock** button.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** and **macOS Big Sur** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue to *click* the **Enable Switch Control** *checkbox*.<sup>1</sup>

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

and works for me to *click* the **Enable Switch Control** *checkbox*:

```applescript
--  # Check to see if System Preferences is 
--  # running and if yes, then close it.
--  # 
--  # This is done so the script will not fail 
--  # if it is running and a modal sheet is 
--  # showing, hence the use of 'killall' 
--  # as 'quit' fails when done so, if it is.
--  #
--  # This is also done to allow default behaviors
--  # to be predictable from a clean occurrence.

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

--  # Make sure System Preferences is not running before
--  # opening it again. Otherwise there can be an issue
--  # when trying to reopen it while it's actually closing.

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

--  # Open System Preferences to the Accessibility pane.

tell application "System Preferences" to ¬
    reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"

--  # Use System Events to achieve the goal.

tell application "System Events"
    tell window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
        
        --  # Wait for target pane to be available.
        --  # The target in this case has a checkbox.
        
        my waitForUIelement(checkbox 1)
        
        --  # Ascertain the target row to select.
        
        set rowSwitchControl to the first row of ¬
            table 1 of scroll area 1 whose value of ¬
            static text 1 of UI element 1 is ¬
            "Switch Control"
        
        --  # Select the target row.
        
        select rowSwitchControl
        
        --  # Wait for target checkbox to be available.
        
        my waitForUIelement(checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of group 1)
        
        --  # Click the Enable Switch Control checkbox.
        
        click checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of group 1
        
    end tell
end tell

delay 0.02

quit application "System Preferences"


--  ## Handler(s) ##

on waitForUIelement(uiElement)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell window 1 of application process ¬
            "System Preferences"
            set i to 0
            repeat until exists uiElement
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 30 then return
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end waitForUIelement
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>